# other loop options for C++

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I was wondering if there were other type of "loops" i could use to create a much easier to read program. I'm playing with the loops and i was wondering if there was a faster or easier method, rather than repeating a loop when a word is typed...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

char guess1, guess2, guess3;
int main()
{
    // the word is cat...

    cout << " Please enter your first guess : _ _ _ \n";
    cin >> guess1;

    if (guess1 == 'c')
    {
        cout << " please enter your second guess: c _ _ \n";
        cin >> guess2;
        if (guess2 == 'a')
        {
            cout << " please enter your second guess: c a _ \n"; 
            cin >> guess3;
        } 
        if (guess2 == 't')
        {
            cout << " please enter your second guess: c _ t \n";
            cin >> guess3; 
        }
        else
        {
            cout << " Wrong answer : # ";
            cin >> guess3;
        }

        if (guess1 == 'a')
        {
             cout << " please enter your second guess: _ a _ \n";
             cin >> guess2;
        }
        if (guess1 == 't')
        {
            cout << " please enter your second guess: _ _ t \n";
            cin >> guess2;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << " Wrong answer : # ";
            cin >> guess2;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to think about how to write this so that it can work with any word with any number of letters.

Comment: your sample doesn't contain any loops, and yet you tagged your question with 'for' and 'while'....so you know what to google for!

Comment: @PaulDixon i tagged this because I know those are other type of loops but I'm not clear if I could use those or how would i use them to prevent using 10 times  "for" loop for every word.

Comment: _'I know those are other type of loops'_ other type vs. what that you've used??? As @PaulDixon already stated, there's not a single loop you're using in your code!

Comment: As an exercise, try writing it with a while() loop, and using a word stored in a null-terminated string. You will want to track which letters they've found, perhaps with a copy of the string, and how many moves they have remaining, so you can break out of the loop when the game is over.

Comment: @g-makulik   I'm using for this trial run "if" loops but I was wondering if I could use a different loop rather than the "if" to shorten the code... I'm using "if" but the code will look too ugly of if I used for every word..

Comment: char guess1, guess2, guess3; might be a 'c' 'a' 't' and the first cin formatted input might fail: which in no wrong answer;

Comment: An `if` statement is no way a loop!!

Comment: You need a state machine.

Comment: @andre Don't overstrain him ...

Comment: @g-makulik learning on my own can be difficult especially  that "if's" seem not to be a loop but I consider them a loop. it's niece to know new information and be able to know just for in case in the future i stumble upon those definitions... "state machine"

Comment: Interesting enough I once had a colleague (also autodidact programmer) who had the same confusion. `if`, `else` and `switch` statements define **branching** paths of the possible program execution. `while`, `for` and `do/while` statements define **repeating** paths of execution, as long the given conditions are met. (and plz. don't confuse this with 'state machine' now, that's a more complex concept!).

Comment: It's much more difficult to understand than what it appear to be. I will probably ask this question within a few months so keep your head out in case you see it.  can you tell what "state machine " refer ?

Comment: @Cris I can give you a framework for C++ state machines: [STTCL](http://makulik.github.io/sttcl) ;o) ... You might want to read about the concept first: [STTCL-Concept](http://makulik.github.io/sttcl/docs/STTCL-Concept.pdf)

Comment: @g-makulik  just saved it to my favorites and downloading thanks for the guide.

Comment: @Cris Note that also your accepted answer realizes (a very simple kind of) state machine (state := `solved`, events := current `guess` value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure there is.  You could do something like this:

```
bool solved = false;
prompt = "Please enter your guess:";
char guess;
char f1='_', f2='_', f3='_'

while(!solved){
   cout << prompt << f1 << f2 << f3 << std::endl;
   cin.get(guess);
   switch(guess){
      case 'c':
        f1 = 'c';
        break;
      case 'a':
        f2 = 'a';          
        break;
      case 't':
        f3 = 't';
        break;
      default:
        cout << "wrong answer";
        break;
   }
   if(f1=='c' && f2=='a' && f3=='t')
     solved = true;
}
```

You could just as easily use while(1) and put a break; in the if condition at the end.
I didn't bother to actually run this so there might be a few errors but hopefully this answers the general question of how you would do such a thing.

Also I noticed you didnt have variables for your guesses, but statially used c _ _ and _ _ t.  What happens when you have 2 guesses?  That is why variables are a good idea to use.

Comment: you forgot the break instructions

Comment: thanks for the example...Now this looks much cleaner and easier to read than using 30 if's for every single word.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a state machine for you. It takes a current state and an input and gives you a new state. If there is no new state for your input the user entered a wrong value.

The advantage of this is you can automate the creation of the state machine to support more words.

```
std::map<std::pair<std::string, char>, std::string> translation;
translation[std::make_pair("_ _ _", 'c')] = "c _ _";
translation[std::make_pair("_ _ _", 'a')] = "_ a _";
translation[std::make_pair("_ _ _", 't')] = "_ _ t";
translation[std::make_pair("c _ _", 'a')] = "c a _";
translation[std::make_pair("c _ _", 't')] = "c _ t";
translation[std::make_pair("_ a _", 't')] = "_ a t";
translation[std::make_pair("_ a _", 'c')] = "c a _";
translation[std::make_pair("_ _ t", 'c')] = "c _ t";
translation[std::make_pair("_ _ t", 'a')] = "_ a t";
translation[std::make_pair("c _ t", 'a')] = "c a t";
translation[std::make_pair("c a _", 't')] = "c a t";
translation[std::make_pair("_ a t", 'c')] = "c a t";

std::string current_state = "_ _ _";
char input;
while(current_state != "c a t") {
    cout << "Please enter your guess: " << current_state << endl;
    cin >> input;
    std::pair<std::string, char> p = std::make_pair(current_state, input);
    if(translation.find(p) == translation.end()) {
        cout << "wrong answer";
        continue;
    }
    current_state = translation[p];
}
```

Comment: its beautiful!!! but really complex. Do you happen to know a website where I could get information about it ? and what is the difference between infinite and just  "state machine"

Comment: @Cris: Technically, nothing -- computers are themselves state machines.  The way the term is typically used, though, a "state machine" has a loop that can change behavior with each iteration, and maintains some variable outside the loop that tells it what its behavior should be this time around.

Comment: All the example I know uses very formal notation and its hard to get what going on because of it. I would suggest getting the above example to work to get a practical understanding of a state machine. Also, the book **"Introduction to Algorithms"** has some useful stuff to say.

Comment: By the way, "complex" is understating a bit.  I wouldn't want to be the one coding the recognition for "supercalifragilisticexpialidocious".  :P  Going this route very nearly mandates writing some code that populates the map with every combination of inputs.

Comment: @cHao That is so true, but the only saving grace is you can make a program to generate it for you.

Comment: An example of 'transition table' oriented state machine implementation. There are more generic alternatives available.

Answer (score 0):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_(computing)#Loops:

> A loop is a sequence of statements which is specified once but which may be carried out several times in succession. The code "inside" the loop (the body of the loop, shown below as xxx) is obeyed a specified number of times, or once for each of a collection of items, or until some condition is met, or indefinitely.

You are only using if statements in your code; those are *not* loops, but simple one-time conditional choices.

See http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/ for some basic information about C++ loops.